# Configure postcss-import to allow "@import" anywhere on a file?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, postcss-loader, postcss-import

While using the latest version of `postcss-import`, I've noticed that it only allows `@import` statements at the top of the files similar to this:

```css
@import "button.css;

.some-class {
  color: red;
}
```

My question here is, is there some way to configure `postcss-import` to allow `@import` statements anywhere in the file? Similar to this:

```css
.some-class {
  color: red;
}

@import "button.css;
```

I'm aware this goes against the upcoming CSS standard. However, I believe I've seen this live in a project and I'm curious how to configure this. This is my `postcss.config.js` file:

```css
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
  ]
}
```

Thanks